# How to create social participation index using STATA?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

In order to construct the Social Participation Variable (SPV) for older adults, the study employs a comprehensive set of questions designed to capture the diverse spectrum of social activities in which older individuals engage. The questionnaire covers various dimensions of social participation, including dining out, leisurely visits to parks or beaches, indoor and outdoor games, interaction with relatives and friends, attendance at cultural performances or cinema, participation in religious functions or events, engagement in political and community meetings, and utilization of technology for activities such as email and net surfing. Respondents express their frequency of involvement in these activities on a nuanced 7-point Likert scale, ranging from daily participation to never or it being not relevant. Given the ordinal nature of the Likert scale responses, an approach such as Factor Analysis or Principal Component Analysis could be employed to identify underlying patterns and interrelationships among the social participation variables. Which will be the best method to apply in this case? Kindly anyone have the STATA syntax of these methodologies?

Comment: What is your goal here? It will be difficult to supply an answer if there isn't a clear question about why you're doing this. Are you just trying to design a new questionairre?

Comment: Dr. Shawn thank you for your response. I want to see the association of economically independent and dependent (Eco Indp =1 and Eco dependent =0)  older people on their social participation. (Apart from social participation I am also going to take into account other parameters such as their decision making, health status and the treatment they received at from other HH members as independent variable)

Comment: But what is the reason for factor analysis or PCA here? It sounds like you already have a scale and want to measure responses between groups. Has this scale been used in the past across studies? If so then sth like EFA or PCA would be unnecessary.